# Upgrade Solution to use FluentValidation Ver 10 Exception Issue

Tags: fluentvalidation

Please I need your help to solve FluentValidation issue. I have an old desktop application which I wrote a few years ago. I used FluentValidation Ver 4 and Now I'm trying to upgrade this application to use .Net framework 4.8 and FluentValidation Ver 10, but unfortunately, I couldn't continue because of an exception that I still cannot fix.

**I have this customer class:**

```
    class Customer : MyClassBase
    {
        string _CustomerName = string.Empty;
        public string CustomerName
        {
            get { return _CustomerName; }
            set
            {
                if (_CustomerName == value)
                    return;

                _CustomerName = value;
            }
        }


        class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
        {
            public CustomerValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(obj => obj.CustomerName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is Empty");
            }
        }

        protected override IValidator GetValidator()
        {
            return new CustomerValidator();
        }

    }
```

**This is my base class:**

```
    class MyClassBase
    {
        public MyClassBase()
        {
            _Validator = GetValidator();
            Validate();
        }

        protected IValidator _Validator = null;

        protected IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> _ValidationErrors = null;

        protected virtual IValidator GetValidator()
        {
            return null;
        }
        public IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> ValidationErrors
        {
            get { return _ValidationErrors; }
            set { }
        }

        public void Validate()
        {
            if (_Validator != null)
            {
                var context = new ValidationContext<Object>(_Validator);
                var results = _Validator.Validate(context); **// <======= Exception is here in this line**
                _ValidationErrors = results.Errors;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ValidationErrors != null && _ValidationErrors.Count() > 0)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
        }

    }
```

When I run the application test I get the below exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Cannot
> validate instances of type 'CustomerValidator'. This validator can
> only validate instances of type 'Customer'.   Source=FluentValidation
> StackTrace:    at
> FluentValidation.ValidationContext`1.GetFromNonGenericContext(IValidationContext context) in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\IValidationContext.cs:line 211    at FluentValidation.AbstractValidator`1.FluentValidation.IValidator.Validate(IValidationContext
> context)

Please, what is the issue here and How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: I wrote my validator class inside my customer class because I don’t want to ruse it any ware else, I created a constructor and I put my customer rules their so the FluentValidation can call up on customer validator class and execute validation. I created virtual method in the customer class named ( GetValidator() ) to return an instance of the validator to my base class to call the validate method and obtaining the results.
what I did works fine on the old version but when I upgrade to FluentValidation 10 I’m getting exception on line “ValidationResult results = _Validator.Validate(this);”

Answer (score 0):

Your overall implementation isn't what I'd consider normal usage however the problem is that you're asking FV to validate the validator instance, rather than the customer instance:

```
var context = new ValidationContext<Object>(_Validator);
var results = _Validator.Validate(context);
```

It should start working if you change it to:

```
var context = new ValidationContext<object>(this);
var results = _Validator.Validate(context);
```

You're stuck with using the `object` argument for the validation context unless you introduce a generic argument to the base class, or create it using reflection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer the issue is resolved now, thank you again.